# How to convert mongo document into key value pair in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, json, mongodb

I am trying to query MongoDB collection using C# .Net. I want to filter the collection based on some criteria, then project only certain fields, and then convert the projection into key-value pair.

I was able to filter and project the way I wanted. However I want to know is there in built method to convert projection into key-value pair?

Here is how my mongo DB document  looks like

```
{
    "_id" : 32178271832,
    "url" : "www.somedomain.com",
    "fileName" : "somefilename.pdf",
    "isDone" : true,
    "client" : ObjectId("56g2e67d7gf2208c2dbe33yt"),
    "startTime" : ISODate("2015-05-23T18:50:11.271Z"),
    "endTime" : ISODate("2015-05-23T18:52:43.819Z"),
    "cost" : 30,
    "taskGroups" : [ 
        {
            "phase" : "phase1",
            "name" : "Some Name",    
            "_id" : ObjectId("43r2e46h7er2208c2geh74e5"),
            "tasks" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("43r2e46h7er2208c2geh74e5"),
                    "input" : [],                 
                    "predecessors" : []
                }
            ]
        }        
    ],
    "context" : {
        "startTime" : ISODate("2016-03-23T18:50:11.271Z"),
        "endTime" : ISODate("2016-03-23T18:52:43.819Z"),
        "state" : "GA",       
        "PHASE1" : {
            "hasaccountnumber" : "Yes",
            "accountnumber" : 1
            "Child1":{
                "Property1": "SomeValue1"
                "Property2" : "SomeValue2"
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Here is my code

```
public static IDictionary<string,string> GetFromMongo()
    {
        var collection = _mongodb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("kunits");
        var filterBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
        var filter = filterBuilder.Eq<bool>("isDone", true) & filterBuilder.Exists("isTransformed", false);

        var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
            .Include("client")
            .Include("url")
            .Include("fileName")
            .Include("context");

        var document = collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).FirstOrDefault();

        IDictionary<string,string> dictionary = ??

        return dictionary;
    }
```

Is there anyway to convert document into dictionary? The document has hierarchical structure.

**Update2**
So this is what I have done. However how do I recursively process if the `BsonValue` is JSON? For example in the above JSON `context` element has hierarchal structure, how do I recursively loop and add each of its field in the dictionary?

```
         var document = collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).FirstOrDefault();
        var docs = new Dictionary<string, BsonValue>();
        foreach (var elm in document.Elements)
        {
            //how to recursively process when elm.value is JSON ??

            docs.Add(elm.Name, elm.Value);

        }
```

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what key(s) and value(s) you want to end up with? You may be able to do a more sophisticated projection, to avoid having to iterate through the returned bson.

Comment: @VinceBowdren see my answer below. I used recursive method to populate dictionary. The mongo document I am dealing with does not have fixed schema

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe FirstOrDefault() is correct on the projection. There is a ToDictionary method that can map what you want:

```
var document = collection.Find(filter).Project(projection);
var dictionary = documents.ToEnumerable().ToDictionary(key => key.client, value => value.url);
```

A different approach

```
var docs = new Dictionary<string, BsonDocument>();
var result = collection.Find(filter).Project(projection);      
result.ForEachAsync((bsonDoc) =>
{
    string name = bsonDoc.GetValue("[Your Dictionary Key]").AsString;
    if (!docs.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        docs[name] = bsonDoc;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see fuent interface `IFindFluent<TDocument, TProjection>` has ToDictionary() method unless its extenstion method in some other namespace. Also note that `context` element has hierarchical structure

Comment: Ah! Correct. You would need ToEnumerable() or ToList() or (await ToListAsync()) ToDictionary is a method on IEnumerable<T>

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I'm still confused about what goes inside ToDictionary(..) method. `document.ToEnumerable().ToDictionary( what does here?);` Note that I don't have schema, I'm using BsonDocument

Comment: I think the second approach might work better. I'm a little confused as to what you want in your dictionary.

Comment: I want to retrieve all the fields in the documents as key-value pair inside dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

finally got it `BsonValue` has property `IsBsonDocument`. We can check that to determine if the vaue is JSON or primitive data type. And then loop recursively

```
public static Dictionary<string, BsonValue> GetFromMongo()
    {
        var collection = _mongodb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("units");
        var filterBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
        var filter = filterBuilder.Eq<bool>("isDone", true) & filterBuilder.Exists("isTransformed", false);

        var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
            .Include("client")
            .Include("url")
            .Include("fileName")
            .Include("context");

        var document = collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).FirstOrDefault();
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, BsonValue>();
        Recurse(document, dictionary);
        return dictionary;
    }

    private static void Recurse(BsonDocument doc, Dictionary<string, BsonValue> dictionary)
    {
        foreach (var elm in doc.Elements)
        {
            if (!elm.Value.IsBsonDocument)
            {
                if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(elm.Name))
                {
                    dictionary.Add(elm.Name, elm.Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Recurse((elm.Value as BsonDocument), dictionary);
            }
        }
    }
```